# Array of Arrays to Object RECURSIVELY in plain JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion

Any Recursive-approach solutions on solving array to object/s (within array) in plain JS (no libraries). Basically I would want to send the same function to itself. At this time I get overwritten the object with the last iteration. 
  i get:

```
{firstName: "Sallito", lastName: "Jordan", age: 16, role: "server"}
```

while i should get:

```
[
    {firstName: 'Eren', lastName: 'Duran', age: 22, role: 'admin'},
    {firstName: 'Sallito', lastName: 'Jordan', age: 16, role: 'server'}
]
```

The original array is:

```
var array = [
    [
         ['firstName', 'Eren'], ['lastName', 'Duran'], ['age', 22], ['role', 'admin']
    ], 
    [
        ['firstName', 'Sallito'], ['lastName', 'Jordan'], ['age', 16], ['role', 'server']
    ]
];
```

my current so-far solution is:

```
function transformData(array) {
   var obj = {};
     for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){        
       for(var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
          for(var k = 0; k < array[i][j].length; k++){
                 if(k === 0){
                 var currentKey = array[i][j][k];
                 var currentValue = array[i][j][k + 1];
                     obj[currentKey] = currentValue;
                 }
          }
      }
  }
     return obj;
  }
```

Please offer just recursive ideas since I know how to do it with forEach and map.reduce ways. I really want to learn recursive-ity. Thanks!

Comment: please add the original data.

Comment: ..or if no recursive solutions... then: how to not overwrite my obj but add the new object to the old one to the array?

Comment: Nina, all is here... the expected result, my code and the result i get. Missing was:  [
    [
        ['firstName', 'Eren'], ['lastName', 'Duran'], ['age', 22], ['role', 'admin']
    ],
    [
        ['firstName', 'Sallito'], ['lastName', 'Jordan'], ['age', 16], ['role', 'server']
    ]
]     //Sorry!

Comment: The sample data you shared is a simple json object string. Its not array. With that data you surely don't need three for loops. What results you are expecting is an array of original object. So its confusing between the input data, logic and what output you want. If you provide the actual data you want to process and the sample of desired output it will be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean with recursion? recursions are usually used for same data pattern (is given) and same processing, which is not given. for every level, you need different initm, processing/collecting and returning. maybe you are looking for something like this: https://gist.github.com/NinaScholz/2a702e1e64b061471ee5

Comment: Recursive is a function that calls itself, just on different level/scope.  Like in: function factorial(n){return factorial(n-1) * n;}  i would want transformData to call itself, since there are more then 1 arrays to evaluate (2 in this case) but could be many more) and since the last array overwrites all previous (in the current incorrect solution).

Comment: Or to find a way to preserve the first obj in the array, and add the next object to the array and the next and so on, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

With pure JS you may do as follows;

```js
var data = [ [ ['firstName', 'Eren'],
               ['lastName', 'Duran'],
               ['age', 22],
               ['role', 'admin'] ],
             [ ['firstName', 'Sallito'],
               ['lastName', 'Jordan'],
               ['age', 16],
               ['role', 'server'] ]
           ],
 objData = data.map(a => a.reduce((o,t) => Object.assign(o,{[t[0]]:t[1]}),{}));
console.log(objData);
```

Explanation: We are applying `.map()` over the main array and it's sub arrays are assigned to `a` argument in it's callback one by one for each turn. So in the first turn `a` is;

```
[ ['firstName', 'Eren'],
  ['lastName', 'Duran'],
  ['age', 22],
  ['role', 'admin'] ],
```

Now, `a` is an array with sub array items (tuples - value pairs) which we would like to join in an object. So applying `.reduce()` to `a` comes very handy for this job;

```
a.reduce((o,t) => Object.assign(o,{[t[0]]:t[1]}),{})
```

Our `.reduce()` function is the type which takes an initial value which is the last part of the above code, `...,{})`. This initially empty object will be assigned to it's callback's first argument `o`. Then every tuple like `['firstName', 'Eren']` will be assigned to the callback's second argument `t` one by one at each turn. They will be accumulated in the empty object by the help of `Object.assign(o,{[t[0]]:t[1]})` instruction. It will take the current empty value of `o` and will merge (join) `{firstname: "Eren"}` to it. Arrow function will return the output of `Object.assign()` as the new `o` value to be used in the next turn. In the next turn `o` is now `{firstname: "Eren"}` and `t` is `["lastname", "Duran"]` and if we substitute the values we now have `Object.assign({firstname: "Eren"},{lastname: "Duran"})` which will return `{firstname: "Eren", lastname: "Duran"}` and this will be returned as our new `o` and so forth...

So i hope it's clear now.

Comment: @Nina Scholz In a comment he mentions "..or if no recursive solutions... then: how to not overwrite my obj ..."

Comment: This code does the job- but i have no idea how. reduce is a black-box to me: what and how o,t work I do not comprehend. I even can read on Mozzilla that o is accumulator and t is value- but how did you arrive at that solution and how did you know in advance to conceive of it- bravo!

Comment: @tonycor nikolauos So you might be confused since the `.reduce()` here uses an empty object `{}` as an initial value. Please check [the second table in this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#How_reduce_works) for step by step explanation. I will also add an explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about recursive solution (and i think you don't need it in this specific case, you will need one if deeper nesting is present, if you have many sub-arrays in sub-arrays...of main array).

Your current solution works almost fine, you just need two fixes, making of new object on each iteration, not at the start of the function (that's why your previous value is overwritten), and one final array to push created objects. Something like this:

```js
var array = [
    [
         ['firstName', 'Eren'], ['lastName', 'Duran'], ['age', 22], ['role', 'admin']
    ], 
    [
        ['firstName', 'Sallito'], ['lastName', 'Jordan'], ['age', 16], ['role', 'server']
    ]
];
function transformData(array) {
   
   final=[];
     for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){  
     var obj = {}; // create new object inside loop -> number of objects, number of arrays
       for(var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
          for(var k = 0; k < array[i][j].length; k++){
                 if(k === 0){
                 var currentKey = array[i][j][k];
                 var currentValue = array[i][j][k + 1];
                     obj[currentKey] = currentValue;
                 }
                 
          }
      }
      final.push(obj); // push objects into final array
  }
  
     return final;
  }
  
  console.log(transformData(array));
```

Here is (imho) simplified version which does the job, too:

```js
var array = [
    [
         ['firstName', 'Eren'], ['lastName', 'Duran'], ['age', 22], ['role', 'admin']
    ], 
    [
        ['firstName', 'Sallito'], ['lastName', 'Jordan'], ['age', 16], ['role', 'server']
    ]
];

function transform(data) {
output=[];
data.forEach(function(el) {
obj={};
for(j=0;j<el.length;j++) {
obj[el[j][0]]=el[j][1];
}
output.push(obj); 
});
return output;

}

console.log(transform(array));
```

P.S. @Redu answer is more javascript-y, and reduce is great, of course, this is just for starters (with explanation what was wrong in original code). ;)